# NSURLSessionDataDelegate didReceiveChallenge callback is not called in ios 8

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession to make https network call. But below callback is not being called in ios 8, but same callback is working in ios 7/ ios 7.1. Are there any changes in ios 8 related to this.

```
public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
```

Comment: same problem for didReceiveResponse and didReceiveData

Comment: same problem here. Did you manage to do anything about it?

Comment: What I have seen is this working perfectly on the simulator (iOS8) but not on the device.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I filed a radar with apple.

Comment: On my project, we authenticated with client certificates and encountered the same problem. Turns out, in 8.x this callback is called once per session, i.e. on first request.
It fires on every request on 7.x, however, which is presumably a bug that Apple has fixed in 8.x, presumably.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour as well.